# How to restart WiFi interface without rebooting (it drops connection)?

Tags: networking, wireless

I boot into ubuntu and it connects to the Wifi network fine. After about 10-15min the DNS stop resolving any website and a couple of minutes later network-managers tells me that I'm disconnected and tries to reconnect constantly to my router and fails to do it. Upon Ubuntu restart everything works fine for the first 10-15min again. When I boot into Mac OS X everything is fine with the same connection!

How do I restart wifi interface? `sudo ifdow wlan0` just tells me that `wlan0 is not configured` and `wlan0` doesn't appear in `/etc/network/interfaces` either, which I find strange.... (unless network-manager is doing it behind my back).

Comment: This looks like a problem with wifi driver. It is unlikely that you will be able to resolve it by just "restarting" network interface. Could you please show the output of `lshw -class network`?

Comment: Must be closed as "No hope".

Comment: I've changed my laptop since this was filed....

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem with ubuntu 15.10 after running on a wired network and having my laptop suspended and resuming when not on a wired network anymore.

I found this blogpost very helpful: http://blog.ostermiller.org/resetting-wireless-networking-on-ubuntu-without-rebooting/

You need to find your driver:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

Look for the wireless controller and in configuration look for driver. In my case:

```
*-network
   description: Network controller
   product: Wireless 8260
   configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
```

All I had to do to fix is run

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: works for ubuntu 16.04

Comment: works for 20.04

Comment: modprobe: FATAL: Module iwlwifi is in use.  - on 22.04

Answer (score 13):

I would have a look at dmesg too, and, after loosing connection, at the last messages of dmesg:

```
dmesg | tail
```

Maybe dropping and reloading your wifi-module helps:

```
sudo rmmod ipw2100
sudo modprobe ipw2100
```

for example, for the intel-chipset. I had random problem with this chispset, which went away, after setting the IRQ in the BIOS.

Comment: For me it was `iwldvm`

Answer (score 5):

You could try to find your wi-fi controller with `lspci`:

```
lspci | grep Network
```

I had the same problem here (using Maverick, I think it's a known bug), and I fixed it with `rmmod` + `modprobe` trick as *@user unknown* answered. Here I'm using a Realtek RTL8191SEvA device, which driver is named `r8192se_pci`.